# PyBrain network gives wrong results

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to train a network for basic image recognition. I tried to train with `ClassificationDataSet` but it gave me strange results. I have 132 samples. Each image is basic grayscale image. Here is my code for training and classification part

## Training

```
import os
import numpy as np

from pybrain.datasets import ClassificationDataSet
from pybrain.supervised import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.tools.xml.networkwriter import NetworkWriter




#letter map
resdict = { '0':0, '1':1 ,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'a':10, 'b':11, 'c':12, 'd':13, 'f':14, 'g':15, 'h':16, 'j':17, 'k':18, 'm':19, 'n':20, 'q':21, 'r':22, 's':23, 't':24, 'v':25, 'w':26, 'x':27,'y':28, 'z':29}

#coordinates of letters
train_ds = ClassificationDataSet(14*24,1)
FOLDER_LOCATION = ''

#loop each box according to x position
for filename in os.listdir(FOLDER_LOCATION):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        index = 0

        #preprocess the image
        # im_grey Grayscale image
        # box coordinates of each letter's bounding box
        # ex : box = {0: (22, 15, 34, 39), 1: (7, 16, 19, 39), 2: (87, 16, 98, 38), 4: (54, 22, 67, 39), 7: (37, 23, 51, 38), 12: (71, 23, 82, 39)}
        (im_grey,box) = preprocess(FOLDER_LOCATION + filename)

        for boxId in sorted(box, key=lambda x: box[x][0]):
            (minX,minY,maxX,maxY) = box[boxId]
            if (maxY - minY) > 10:
                #this is a blob that we care
                region = im_grey.crop((box[boxId])).resize((14, 24))
                label = resdict[filename[index]]

                srcdata = np.ravel(np.array(region) / 255)
                print filename,filename[index],label,srcdata

                train_ds.addSample(srcdata,label)
                index = index + 1

net = buildNetwork(train_ds.indim, 98, train_ds.outdim, bias=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, train_ds)
print "start training"
trainer.trainUntilConvergence()


print "finish training"
file = "newNetwork.xml"
NetworkWriter.writeToFile(net, file)
```

## Classification

```
import os
import numpy as np

from pybrain.tools.xml.networkreader import NetworkReader

FOLDER_LOCATION = ''
net  = NetworkReader.readFrom('newNetWork.xml')
resdict = { '0':0, '1':1 ,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'a':10, 'b':11, 'c':12, 'd':13, 'f':14, 'g':15, 'h':16, 'j':17, 'k':18, 'm':19, 'n':20, 'q':21, 'r':22, 's':23, 't':24, 'v':25, 'w':26, 'x':27,'y':28, 'z':29}

for filename in os.listdir(FOLDER_LOCATION):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        index = 0

        #preprocess the image
        # im_grey Grayscale image
        # box coordinates of each letter's bounding box
        # ex : box = {0: (22, 15, 34, 39), 1: (7, 16, 19, 39), 2: (87, 16, 98, 38), 4: (54, 22, 67, 39), 7: (37, 23, 51, 38), 12: (71, 23, 82, 39)}
        (im_grey,box) = preprocess(FOLDER_LOCATION + filename)

        for boxId in sorted(box, key=lambda x: box[x][0]):
            (minX,minY,maxX,maxY) = box[boxId]
            if (maxY - minY) > 10:
                #this is a blob that we care
                region = im_grey.crop((box[boxId])).resize((14, 24))
                label = resdict[filename[index]]
                srcdata = np.ravel(np.array(region) / 255)
                out = net.activate(srcdata)
                l = out.tolist()
                max_v = max(l)
                print "======START============"
                max_i = l.index(max_v)
                print filename,filename[index],label
                print "Max", max_v
                print "Guess:", max_i
                print "RAW:", out
                print "======END============"

                index = index + 1
```

When I try to classify it prints wrong values such as

```
======START============
3hmns5.jpg 3 3
Max 3.20058748934
Guess: 0
RAW: [ 3.20058749]
======END============
======START============
3hmns5.jpg h 16
Max 16.3602030071
Guess: 0
RAW: [ 16.36020301]
======END============
======START============
3hmns5.jpg m 19
Max 19.8885589891
Guess: 0
RAW: [ 19.88855899]
======END============
======START============
3hmns5.jpg n 20
Max 23.2138122864
Guess: 0
RAW: [ 23.21381229]
======END============
======START============
3hmns5.jpg s 23
Max 22.7990777611
Guess: 0
RAW: [ 22.79907776]
======END============
======START============
3hmns5.jpg 5 5
Max 5.5891692451
Guess: 0
RAW: [ 5.58916925]
======END============
```

Sometimes digit part seems OK but sometimes it needs to rounding up and sometimes it is totally wrong. What is the correct way to train this kind of network?

Comment: If you are doing image recognition you may want to check out caffe which is a library for python that was built for image recognition

Comment: Thanks but it seems too complicated. I tried to read documentation but frankly I found it very distracting. I managed to recognize the images by PyBrain using `train_ds = ClassificationDataSet(14*24,nb_classes=30)` and then using `train_ds._convertToOneOfMany()` I will appreciate if you direct me to sample code which directly deals with PIL image and train and classify the images.